# Fix orphan titles in columns

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I'm currently stuck on a CSS printing issue that is printing columns without having orphan titles, like in the following example:

[image: columns]

https://codepen.io/sjeannin/pen/wrXoRG

```
<div class="two-columns">
  <h1>Hello, Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <h1>Other title, world!</h1>
  <h2> Subtitle, world</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>

.two-columns {
  column-count: 2;
}

h1, h2 {
  break-after: avoid;
}
```

My goal is to make a CSS sheet for printing a well structured, 40 pages long document using Google Chrome headless. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with orphans in the rendered documents: in the previous example, I'd prefer having the second title inside the second column, with its associated content.

Is there a CSS way to make this work? Should I turn to custom div's in my document's code that would force column jumps?

Thanks!

~spj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came with a solution that works in 90% of my cases:

```
* + h2,* + h3,* + h4,* + h5,* + h6 {
    break-inside: avoid-column!important;
    break-after: avoid-column!important;
    page-break-inside: avoid!important;
    page-break-after: avoid!important;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid!important;
    -webkit-column-break-after: avoid!important;
}
h2 + *, h3 + *, h4 + *, h5 + *, h6 + * {
    break-before: avoid-column!important;
    page-break-before: avoid!important;
    -webkit-column-break-before: avoid!important;
}
h1:not(:first-child) {
    break-before: column;
}
```

(This is a temporary solution, because YES I know it is plain ugly and I'm still looking for a generic way to print a PDF with zero h1-h6 orphans)

Answer (score 0):

What about using :not(X) selector? Selecting all but the first H1 to break before a column?

```
h1:not(:first-child) {
  break-before: column;
}
```

Comment: This is a very good start! I now try to come with a generic solution for all h1-6 :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from Google Chrome itself, I tried with Weasyprint and it works like a charm when using the ugly CSS I just had written!